# How to failover to an AWS RDS MySQL replica in Java

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS MySQL instance on which I have set Multi-AZ redundancy to True. I also have a read-replica that I will use for read-only queries. I am using C3P0 as my connection pool. AWS gives the endpoint for the master instance and for the read-replica, but does not give an endpoint for the redundant master. I am creating two connection pools, one for read access and one for write access. How do I ensure that my service will be able to reach the redundant master if the master fails over? I read about setting the ttl, I am setting that to 30. However, I rebooted the master (and ticked the failover button), but my service was unable to write data until the master had finished rebooting and came back online. I am using Guice to inject the connection pools into my code.

Comment: If you ticked the box to failover then the master never "came back online". The master became the standby and the standby was promoted to master. The DNS would have switched so that the address you were using to connect to the master would have switched to the new master (old standby).

Comment: You're correct, I used the wrong terminology. How do I detect this switch of the DNS in my code? I set java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "10"); as mentioned in the AWS docs (they said 60 seconds, but I was trying it at 10)

Comment: That should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the failover to work. (It was actually working, I was just not waiting long enough to see it happen). I had some C3P0 settings that were set too high, that was causing C3P0 to not see that the connections were failed.